# ind the values of the constants a and b for which the function is differentiable.

Tags: calculus

For the following system of functions, find the values of the constants $a$ and $b$ for which the function is differentiable at $x=\frac \pi4$ .

$$f(x)=ax+b,   x \leq \frac \pi4$$

$$f(x)=\tan x, \frac \pi4 \lt x \lt \frac \pi2$$

$$\frac {d} {dx} \tan x=sec^2 x$$  $$\frac {d} {dx} ax+b = a$$
$$a=sec^2 (\frac \pi4) = 2 $$
but I am totally confused what to do next.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It must be continuous before it can be differentiable.

Comment: so, it means, that $ax+b=tanx$ so $b=2\pi/4$ ?

Comment: It means that $2x+b=\tan x$ when $x=\frac\pi4,$ yes, but you have incorrectly solved for $b$.

Comment: ah, right its $-2\pi/4$

Comment: Closer, but still not quite. Start by writing $$2x+b=\tan x,$$ then rewrite it, replacing *every instance* of $x$ with $\frac\pi4.$

Comment: wait, wait, wait. can't get it. $\tan (\pi/4)=0),$ so $2*\pi/4+b=0$, or is there a mistake?

Comment: There is a mistake: $\tan\frac\pi4=1.$

Comment: ah, right. so $b=1-2pi/4$

Comment: There you go! ${}{}$

Comment: thanks, it has turned out to be easier, than I have expected.

Comment: You are welcome. You got off to a great start!